# Asking the user what kind of function they want

Tags: python

I have an area calculator and I want the user in the beginning choose what thing to calculate instead of going down the list. is there a code for to ask the user, and stop the other code. And after the user chooses, take the user to that specific function. Then afterwards, take them back to the ask screen? Need some advice.

```
import math

def square():
    print ("Area of Square")
    print ("")
    S = float(input("Enter Length of Square:"))
    A = round((S**2),3)
    print (A, "is the Area of the Square")
    print("")
    print("")
square()

def rectangle():
    print("Area of Rectangle")
    print ("")
    L = float(input("Enter Length of Rectangle:"))
    W = float(input("Enter Width of Rectangle:"))
    A = round((L*W),3)
    print (A, "is the Area of the Rectangle")
    print("")
    print("")
rectangle()

def paralelogram():
    print("Area of Paralelogram")
    print("")
    B = float(input("Enter Base of Paralelogram:"))
    H = float(input("Enter Height of Paralelogram:"))
    A = round((B*H),3)
    print (A, "is the Area of the Paralelogram")
    print("")
    print("")
paralelogram()

def triangle():
    print("Area of Triangle")
    print("")
    B = float(input("Enter Base of Triangle:"))
    H = float(input("Enter Height of Triangle:"))
    A = round(((B*H)/2),3)
    print (A, "is the Area of the Triangle")
    print("")
    print("")
triangle()

def circle():
    print("Area of Circle")
    print("")
    r = float(input("Enter Radius of Circle:"))
    A = round(math.pi*(r**2),3)
    print (A, "is the Area of the Circle")
    print("")
    print("")
circle()

def trapezoid():
    print("Area of Trapezoid")
    print("")
    B1 = float(input("Enter Base 1 of Trapezoid:"))
    B2 = float(input("Enter Base 2 of Trapezoid:"))
    H = float(input("Enter Height of Trapezoid:"))
    A = round((((B1+B2)/2)*H),3)
    print (A, "is the Area of the Trapezoid")
    print("")
    print("")
trapezoid()

def sphere():
    print("Area of Sphere")
    print("")
    r = float(input("Enter Radius of Sphere:"))
    A = round((((r**2)*4)*math.pi),3)
    print (A, "is the Area of the Sphere")
    print("")
sphere()
```

Comment: why you call your all functions?They are not classes.

Comment: Yes there is code to do that and you should try to write it yourself.

Comment: what is exactly is your question? what have you tried?  What errors are you getting?   You can print out a menu, wait for input, parse the input and then call that function.

Comment: Also you can do that with a simple _while True:_ and _if something:call some function_ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more Pythonic way of doing this is to store references to the functions in a dictionary:

```
area_func = {'triangle': triangle, 'square': square, 'rectangle': rectangle,
             'paralelogram': paralelogram, 'circle': circle, 'trapezoid': trapezoid,
             'sphere': sphere}

while True:
    shape = input('What shape do you want to calculate the area of ("stop" to end)?')
    if shape == 'stop':
        break
    try:
        area_func[shape]()
    except KeyError:
        print("I don't recognise that shape.")
        continue
```

This works because functions, like everything else in Python, are objects. So you can store them as values in a dictionary, assign variable names to them, etc. The expression `area_func[shape]` is thus a reference to a function, for example, `triangle`, which can then be called (by appending `()`, an empty set of parentheses since your functions don't take any arguments).

As others have noted, you probably don't want the function calls after each definition. And, to be pedantic, parallelogram is the correct spelling.

Comment: why did you use `()` in `area_func[shape]()`

Comment: See the explanation in my latest edit. The `()` turns the reference to the function into a _call_ of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a while loop.

```
#your functions here

options="""1-)Square
2-)Rectangel
3-)Paralelogram
4-)Triangle
5-)Trapezoid
6-)sphere
"""
while True:
    print (options)
    user=input("Please choose a valid option: ")
    if user=="1":
        square()
        continue
    elif user=="2":
        rectangel()
        continue
    ..
    ..
    ..  #same codes with elif statement till 6.
    ..
    else:
        print ("It's not a valid choose.Please choose a valid one.")
```